# Unity | Scale an object between two points (2D)

Tags: unity-game-engine, math, vector, distance, point

I have a point A and a point B, with a distance AB between both. I also have an object K with a width 1 and a height 1.

Given that, I have to scale the object K to fit between the points A and B. After centering the object in the position `(B - A) / 2`, what should I do?

[Descriptive picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeDdK.png)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, set the transform of the object to the desired scale which would be just the distance AB.
Then you need to set the orientation as well. You can do that by calculating the direction between the two points but I would tend to believe that the "lookAt" function might do exactly that and thus would be a shortcut: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html